# Sun shining up a dog’s arse?

Tags: idioms

There used to be (probably still is) a saying that had the sun shining up a dog’s arse ocasionally. Can you remind be how it went?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sun don't shine on the same dog's ass every day, but, mister you ain't seen a ray of light since you got here.

[Hoosiers - Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hoosiers)

Comment: i said it to myself today after one of the guys in my fantasy football league scored 170 points... well, the sun shines on a dogs ass every once in a while